# Установка библиотеки c Github и работа CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

пытаюсь понять как платформо независимо добавить библиотеку в свой проект.

Библиотека следующая:
https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets Что сделал я при добавлении? Создал в корне проекта папку lib и там написал команду git clone, далее создал в директории lib CMakeList.txt следующего содержания:

```
project(uws C CXX)


add_library(uws INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(uws INTERFACE .)
```

Далее, в основном Cmakelist сделал это:

```
# задать версию CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
# описание проекта
project(server)

# задать переменную CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD как 17
# тем самым используя 17 стандарт C++
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# скомпилировать исполняемый файл с заданным именем из (списка) исходников
add_executable(server main.cpp)

# добавляем субдиректорию содержащую библиотеку
add_subdirectory(lib)

# линкуем бибилиотеку и наш исполняемый файл
target_link_libraries(server uws)
```

Теперь можно добавлять файлы в мой проект вот таким образом:

> #include "uWebSockets/src/App.h"

Хотя я предполагал, что путь будет uws/App.h, ну да ладно. При попытке компиляции все ругается на то, что не хватает еще каких то хедеров. Как правильно провести установку? у меня есть mingw32 (возможно я за него делаю какую то работу и все можно проще и быстрее)

Работаю в Clion так что вариант установить все с помощью vcpkg не подходит.

**UPD**

Не хватает

> C:\cpp\server\lib\uWebSockets\src\PerMessageDeflate.h(45): fatal error
> C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: zlib.h: No such file or
> directory

Возможно я пропустил какой то важный этап в установке? я  так понял оно будет сейчас требовать все зависимости начиная от этого zlib заканчивая libuv

Comment: думаю, хорошо бы написать, каких именно хедеров оно не может найти.

Comment: @KoVadim обновил информацию

Comment: Библиотека - header-only. Ее не нужно компилировать и писать в `target_link_libraries`. Достаточно указать в своем CMakeLists путь к ее хедерам.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вписал и скачалось три сабмодуля, но проблема не решена) Хотелось бы узнать что "как максимум"

Comment: @KarlosMargaritos Пока отвечали, понял что не поможет и удалил комментарий. :)

Comment: А как платформо независимо указать путь к хедерам? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Просто `target_include_directories`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat    Написал вот так 'target_include_directories(server PRIVATE ./lib/uWebSockets/src)' хедера добавились но ругается все равно что нет zlib Хочу также отметить, что вот этот путь до папки вида ./lib/ это точно платформо независимое решение?

Comment: А что в нем платформозависимого? Только что руками надо качать туда библиотеку, но это можно сделать сабмодулем, например.

Comment: Про `zlib.h` - нужно как-то поставить и подключить зависимости, по одной. Судя по сабмодулям нужны libdeflate и usockets, и похоже еще zlib. Раз у них все на мейкфайлах, потребуется программа Make. Я бы начал с [установки MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) - в нем найдете Make, новенький GCC (свой GCC, он же MinGW, лучше удалите чтобы не мешался), и уже собранные libdeflate, zlib (все это надо поставить из пакетного менеджера, по ссылке описано). Дальше Мейком собрать usockets. Потом в своем CMakeLists как-то подключить libdeflate, zlib, и свежесобранный usockets.

Comment: Спрашивайте если на каком-то шаге застрянете, но отвечу уже завтра...

Comment: Не мучайтесь, используйте vcpkg: `vcpkg install uwebsockets`

Comment: @Genjutsu у меня его не получилось присобачить к Clion